# Building the Page Contents page using XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I am trying to build the CONTENTS Page for my book in following format but no luck.

```
Table of contents.....................................1
Definition............................................2
Types of Definition...................................5
etc...................................................7
```

the thing is i am not able to understand how i should make it aligned like about and fill the dots.

If any one have any idea about this please let me know.

Thank you in advance

Regards,
Mona

Answer (score 1):

Turn on justification for the line (at least the last line and optionally for the other lines), and separate the section title from the page number citation using a leader of dots.  Use indents to cover off the wrapping of long titles.

Here is an example where I've made the section title and the page number linkable:

```
<block text-align-last="justify"
      end-indent="1cm" start-indent="1cm">
 <basic-link internal-destination="N36">Second Title</basic-link>
 <leader leader-pattern="dots"/>
 <basic-link internal-destination="N36">
  <page-number-citation ref-id="N36"/>
 </basic-link>
</block>
```

There are helpful diagrams on pages 162-170 of my XSL-FO book that is available for free download on a "try and buy" basis at http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training/#pfux ... if you decide not to pay for the book, please delete the copy that you download for free.